# CSS menu border appears broken on a hovered state?

Tags: html, css

I need your help, I can't seem, for the life of me be able to figure out so as to why my CSS menu border (specifically in the middle) appear to be broken? It almost looks like it has 1 extra pixel of a white border or something?

The rendering browser is MS Edge. What can I do?

Here's a pic of the problem (hovered):
[image: problem]

```css
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 1500px;
  background: transparent;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.label {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #7f7f7f;
  transition: background 0.1s, color 0.1s;
}

.label:hover {
  background: #d8d8d8;
}

.label:active {
  background: #ccc;
}

.input:focus+.label {
  z-index: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .label {
    width: auto;
  }
}

.panel {
  display: none;
  padding: 30px 30px 30px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 700px;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .panel {
    order: 99;
  }
}

.input:checked+.label {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border-top: 1px solid green;
  border-left: 1px solid green;
  border-right: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.input:checked+.label+.panel {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs" style="margin: auto;">
  <input name="tabs" type="radio" id="tab-1" checked="checked" class="input" />
  <label for="tab-1" class="label">Workspace Info</label>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>The orange (specifically, the sweet orange) is the fruit of the citrus species Citrus × sinensis in the family Rutaceae</p>
    <p>The fruit of the Citrus × sinensis is considered a sweet orange, whereas the fruit of the Citrus × aurantium is considered a bitter orange. The sweet orange reproduces asexually (apomixis through nucellar embryony); varieties of sweet orange arise
      through mutations.
    </p>
  </div>

  <input name="tabs" type="radio" id="tab-2" class="input" />
  <label for="tab-2" class="label">Employee Info</label>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>The tangerine (Citrus tangerina) is an orange-colored citrus fruit that is closely related to, or possibly a type of, mandarin orange (Citrus reticulata).</p>
    <p>The name was first used for fruit coming from Tangier, Morocco, described as a mandarin variety. Under the Tanaka classification system, Citrus tangerina is considered a separate species.</p>
  </div>
  <input name="tabs" type="radio" id="tab-3" class="input" />
  <label for="tab-3" class="label">Service Requests</label>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>A clementine (Citrus ×clementina) is a hybrid between a mandarin orange and a sweet orange, so named in 1902. The exterior is a deep orange colour with a smooth, glossy appearance. Clementines can be separated into 7 to 14 segments. Similarly to tangerines,
      they tend to be easy to peel.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

Issue due to font-weight:bold. try change to font-weight:500.

```
.label {
width: 100%;
padding: 10px;
background: #e5e5e5;
cursor: pointer;
font-weight: 500; /* Newly added */
color: #7f7f7f;
transition: background 0.1s, color 0.1s;
}
```